# What happens to the state of a sql connection in using block after the exception encountered is re-thrown?

Tags: .net, exception, ado.net, sqlconnection

```
Try
    xConn.ConnectionString = xConnBuilder.ConnectionString
    xConn.Open()
    Throw New Exception("Something")
Catch ex As Exception
    Throw
Finally
    If xConn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        xConn.Close()
    End If
End Try
```

What happens to the connection object after the exception is thrown and re-thrown maintaining the stack trace, is it closed, because the finally block is not reached in case of exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally block contains the code that must be executed no matter weather there was an error/exception or not.

Answer (score 1):

In your sample code the connection will be closed.
The finally code block is always executed irrespective of exception occurs or not.